# problemas con el GIT merge y archivos de desarrollo/produccion

Tags: git

Como es de esperar, tengo una App Web, del que tengo una versión "beta" en desarrollo en el que pruebo las nuevas características antes de publicarlas en la versión publica, la cuestión es que necesito que la app web distinga de si es la versión BETA o la versión de producción, y para eso tengo, en la rama de producción como en la rama beta un archivo que lo diferencia

la cuestión es que quiero que al hacer MERGE, el GIT no cambie el archivo "production.py" que esta en la rama de producción por el "production.py" de la rama de desarrollo

Answer (score 0):

Para este tipo de cosas es mejor que uses variables de entorno que puedas cambiar al momento de arrancar la aplicación, y no a través de información en ficheros. Tu `production.py` podría ser el mismo en ambas ramas, pero internamente en lugar de definir una constante "a pelo", usar `os.getenv()` para leer el valor de una variable de entorno.

Por ejemplo:

```py
import os

despliegue = os.getenv("DESPLIEGUE", "BETA")
```

La variable de entorno la asignarías desde el shell, con `export DESPLIEGUE=produccion` (si la variable no está fijada el código que escribí usará el valor por defecto "BETA").

Si ejecutas desde dentro de un contenedor puedes fijar la variable de entorno *dentro* del contenedor con `docker run ...(otras opciones)... -e DESPLIEGUE=produccion imagen`. Y si lo vas a lanzar con docker-compose también hay forma de poner el valor de esa variable en el `docker-compose.yaml`.

Finalmente, este mecanismo de las variables de entorno se usa también para no meter en el código fuente datos "sensibles" como claves privadas, contraseñas de conexión a base de datos, etc. Si al final acabas teniendo muchas variables de entorno puedes escribir un archivo llamado `.env` que contenga todas ellas y sus valores. Este fichero obviamente **no estaría bajo control de versiones**. Puedes escribir código python que lo lea, o puedes dejarlo como estaba (tomándolo de `os.getenv()`), pues hay herramientas que pueden leer ese .env y usarlo para definir todas las variables de entorno necesarias. `docker-compose` por ejemplo soporta ese mecanismo y puede leer variables de un `.env`. Y python tiene la biblioteca `python-dotenv` que puede leer el `.env` y usarlo para fijar las variables de entorno.